# Execute php file that generate PDF with jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, pdf

I have this form:

```
<form action="tcpdf/examples/example_0611.php" method="get">
Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
E-mail: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

and on example_0611.php file I have:

```
$myName = $_GET["name"];
$myEmail = $_GET["email"];
etc...// CODE THAT GENERATE PDF
```

So here when I submit file I get PDF file from example_0611.php file. And everything is fine.

But is it possible to send name and email with .ajax jquery to example_0611.php file and from return or on success to get generated PDF file from example_0611.php file ?

I try to send name and mail with ajax as data to .php file and this return me sucess but browser dont download generated php file... WHY?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this in javascript:

`window.location = "/generatePDF.php?name=NAME&email=EMAIL"`

And it should download your file.

Comment: For saving, I would recommend sessions as I wrote below. But with your method, there lasts an empty white page in the clients browser. Better is to make it open in new tab with native HTML (target) and return true/false for onsubmit.

Comment: For your new answer: I would not recommend GET parameters because your have to think about encoding and there is a length limit. (`encodeURIComponent()`)

Answer (score 1):

> try to send name and mail with ajax as data to .php file and this return me sucess

Send the data via Ajax like before and save it to session:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['key'] = $value; // Example
```

Now you can send the user to download page, where you send the headers. Direct download via Ajax is not possible, because the headers are the wrong. But you can make the form target to `_blank`, so the generation/download script tab is closed automatically after download in the most browsers.